# Select a Particular value from a table via vba

Tags: vba, excel

This seems like an easy item - but I can't find anything on it (could be the brain cells aren't firing correctly)

I have an excel worksheet with a table in it that has parmeters. The Table Name is Parms. It has two columns 'Key' and 'Value'. What I want to do it provide a key and get the corresponding  value. If the the table holds the keys: Alpha, Bravo, Charlie and the corresponding values are 10, 25, and 75. and I ask for Bravo = I like to get 25 back.

Might look something like:

x = oSht.ListObjects("Parameters").Range("['Bravo',[Value]]").value

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two possible solutions. First:

Assuming keys are in column A, rows 1 through 6, values are in column B, key which we look for is in C2, then this should do the trick:

```
=IF(IFERROR(MATCH(C2;A1:A6;0);0);OFFSET(A1;MATCH(C2;A1:A6;0)-1;1;1;1);"")
```

Second, code solution:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
Dim i, j As Integer
Dim key As String
Dim answer As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
key = "Bravo"

For i = 1 To ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1
    If ws.Cells(i, 1).Value = key Then
        answer = ws.Cells(i, 2).Value
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```